# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 49-53: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encode, codec

This is my code for creating a file

```
character = open(namecharacter + '.txt', 'wt')
    character.write('Name: ' + namecharacter + '\n\nClass: ' + category + '\n\nHealth: ♥♥♥♥♥\n\nStrenght: ' + str(strength_new) +
                    '\n\nDefense: ' + str(defense_new) + '\n\nDexterity: ' + str(dexterity_new) +
                    '\n\nRanged Attack: ' + str(ranged_new) + '\n\nMelee Attack: ' +
                    str(melee_new) + '\n\nSpeed: ' + str(speed_new))
    character.close()
```

Then it gives this error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Fantasy Board Game\Game Program\DandD style game.py", line 566, in <module>
str(ranged_new) + '\n\nMelee Attack: ' + str(melee_new) + '\n\nSpeed: ' + str(speed_new))
File "C:\Users\Jedidiah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
  return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 49-53: character maps to <undefined>
```

The line that is wrong is:

```
str(melee_new) + '\n\nSpeed: ' + str(speed_new))
```

I know this has been asked before but I didn't really understand how to fix it and I didn't know why is was happening. all of my variables in the code have been declared before and all work in other lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

The `♥` characters you are trying to print do not exist in the default encoding `cp1252` being used by your `open`.  You can pass the encoding you want to use as a parameter, for example:

```
character = open(namecharacter + '.txt', 'wt', encoding='utf8')
```

Full example (make sure to save the file in the declared source encoding of UTF-8):

```
#coding: utf8

datafmt = '''\
Name:          {namecharacter}
Class:         {category}
Health:        ♥♥♥♥♥
Strength:      {strength_new}
Defense:       {defense_new}
Dexterity:     {dexterity_new}
Ranged Attack: {ranged_new}
Melee Attack:  {melee_new}
Speed:         {speed_new}
'''

player = {'namecharacter' : 'Mark',
          'category' : 'Wizard',
          'strength_new' : 10,
          'defense_new' : 100,
          'dexterity_new' : 15,
          'ranged_new' : 10,
          'melee_new' : 5,
          'speed_new' : 10}

with open(player['namecharacter'] + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as character:
    character.write(datafmt.format(**player))
```

Output:

```
Name:          Mark
Class:         Wizard
Health:        ♥♥♥♥♥
Strength:      10
Defense:       100
Dexterity:     15
Ranged Attack: 10
Melee Attack:  5
Speed:         10
```

Comment: (1) you don't need `coding: utf8` on Python 3 (2) It is worth mentioning it explicitly that the character encoding of the Python source code (utf-8 is the default on Python 3) is unrelated to the character encoding of the text file in any way e.g., any character encoding that can represent `♥` (U+2665 Unicode codepoint) will do here (e.g., `utf-16` -- it is more likely that notepad will recognize utf-16 file on Windows).